# AccessViolation when calling Marshal.Copy using user32 SendMessage

Tags: c#, winforms, pointers, ipc, sendmessage

I'm writing a new tool for my organisation that has to talk via SendMessage to a legacy tool.

I just made a test app using code from here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/6444/

I have edited the send code to match my purpose. But I'm having some problems receiving messages in my "GetMessage" form. The message does go through but the program breaks when trying to convert the data into a string.

Here's my code:

Send:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(null, "GetMessage");

    if (hwnd != null)
    {            
        string message = textBox1.Text + "-" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
        cds.dwData = 0;
        cds.lpData = (int)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(message);
        cds.cbData = message.Length;
        SendMessage(hwnd, (int)WM_COPYDATA, 0, ref cds);
    }
}
```

Recieve:

```
private const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x4A;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    public int dwData;
    public int cbData;
    public int lpData;
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_COPYDATA:

            COPYDATASTRUCT CD = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
            byte[] B = new byte[CD.cbData];
            IntPtr lpData = new IntPtr(CD.lpData);

            //string test = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(lpData, CD.lpData); // this doesn't work either
            Marshal.Copy(lpData, B, 0, CD.cbData); // access violation here
            string strData = Encoding.Default.GetString(B);
            listBox1.Items.Add(strData);

            break;

        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

I've tried setting the message string in send to a field (so it doesn't go out of scope), setting the "int wParam" argument of Send Message to an "IntPtr" and using IntPtr.Zero instead of 0 in my SendMessage call, and null terminating the string as below:

```
cds.lpData = (int)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(message + '\0');
cds.cbData = (message+'\0').Length;
```

Still getting the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: Your declarations are wrong, this code cannot work in 64-bit mode and will crash as documented when you try it anyway.  Get better ones from the http://pinvoke.net website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, I believe that the problem was that I was using int instead of IntPtr for my SendMessage and COPYDATASTRUCT.

I got this information from http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage and http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COPYDATASTRUCT.html

Here's the working code:

```
private const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr dwData;
    public int cbData;
    public IntPtr lpData;
}
```

Send:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
//static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam); // original
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT cds); // override

private void SendMsg()
{
    if (_hwnd != null)
    {
        COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
        cds.dwData = IntPtr.Zero;
        cds.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(stockCode);
        cds.cbData = stockCode.Length;
        SendMessage(_hwnd, (int) WM_COPYDATA, IntPtr.Zero, ref cds);
    }
}
```

Recieve:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_COPYDATA:

            COPYDATASTRUCT CD = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
            byte[] B = new byte[CD.cbData];
            IntPtr lpData = CD.lpData;

            Marshal.Copy(lpData, B, 0, CD.cbData);
            string strData = Encoding.Default.GetString(B);
            listBox1.Items.Add(strData);

            break;

        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

I believe this is working on 64bit windows.

Comment: Two ptential gotchas. (a) Memory leak because your code doesn't explicitly release the memory allocated by StringToHGlobalAnsi; see the online ref for an example (but release in the Receive code!). (b) On a machine whose code page is multibyte e.g. Chinese, the string will be truncated when copied because you count .NET characters instead of encoded bytes. Probably better to use PtrToHGlobalAnsi and ignore cbData (if you care about this case).

Comment: PtrToStringAnsi, not PtrToHGlobalAnsi.

Comment: Thanks @groverboy. I'm only writing the send code, the "recieve" part is actually legacy code (I wrote the recieve above to test my code). Do I need to worry about any memory leaks in the send code above? I'll double check with them that there's not memory leaks in the existing legacy recieve code.

Comment: Correction: I forgot that SendMessage is synchronous, which means that the send code _can_ release the allocated memory. In fact it _should_, as noted in [WM_COPYDATA message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx). Here's another example, which also correctly declares  COPYDATASTRUCT: [Interprocess Communication Between .NET and MFC Using WM_COPYDATA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22402/Interprocess-Communication-Between-NET-and-MFC-Usi).